# Cannot add file to solution: "A file or folder with the name [name] already exists"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I attempt to add *any* file to my project, I get this error:

> A file or folder with the name azazaz.cs already exists.
>
> Please give a unique name to the item you are adding, or delete the existing item first.'

There have been no updates to Visual Studio recently. The problem only occurs in this one project. It works properly on other computers.

What I've tried so far:

- I tried many different names, checked for hidden files, and checked the folder location.
- Deleted the repository and downloaded again (through GitHub), as suggested by AbhishekP.
- Deleted the "ComponentModelCache" folder in "AppData\Local" folder as suggested by Srikanth.
- Checked the ".csproj" folder for the file name in the error message, but it doesn't exist.

I can't really start over and create a new project.

Comment: No updates were done, problems occurs only in this one project. It works properly on other computers.

Comment: Updated, Multiple answers were given before change. And I believe with change should be alot better, please remove hold

Comment: Exactly my point of view @GrantWinney I'm trying to post all the information I can. I've posted what the error was, What I've tried. The question is trivial.. what's unclear about it toward why it should be put on hold?

Comment: I completely Understand if there's not much to go on, I'm trying my best to provide all of the necessary information. But if there were 3 possible answers and it does say something about the clarity of the question. If there's no answers that can help fix this bug then that's fine but to say it's unclear and put it on hold?? I've layed out the information in such a format that 3 other people were able to understand so how's it unclear?

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 5):

Delete the "ComponentModelCache" folder under the below mentioned path and restart Visual Studio. For my install of Visual Studio 2012 the following is the path. Search according to your Visual Studio version.

“C:\Users\ic016028\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\”

Comment: this solution and restarting visual studio helped me

Answer (score 1):

Open your project .csproj file in notepad. After that delete  azazaz.cs  from references.

Answer (score 1):

Go to that project folder location and delete the same project you have created. Issue is that, you might have created one project with same name and removed it. but that project exists in location. So first delete it and create new one. ask me anythins is confusing.

Comment: I've deleted the repository completely, downloaded again through github and still repeating. Can't really start over and create a new one.